# how to display tabs in vim at startup like here?

Tags: vim, configuration

how to display tabs in vim at startup like here (top)?

[image: capture]

How do I do it in the config?

Comment: See `:help 'showtabline'`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `set showtabline=2` to your `~/.vimrc`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `set showtabline=2` to your `~/.vimrc`. 
According to `:help showtabline`:

```
The value of this option specifies when the line with tab page labels                                                                     
will be displayed:                                                                                                                        
    0: never                                                                                                                          
    1: only if there are at least two tab pages                                                                                       
    2: always
```